# Is there any way to present an UIPopover from an UITableView index?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

I would like to present an UIPopover from an UITableView specific index.
Here's my code:

```
if (indexPath.row == 5) {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    EnginesPopoverController  *enginesPopoverController = [[EnginesPopoverController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EnginesPopoverController" bundle:nil];

    UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:enginesPopoverController];

    self.popoverController = popover;
    popoverController.delegate = self;

    [popover release];
    [enginesPopoverController release];

    CGPoint point = {670, 600};
    CGSize size = {450, 216};

    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, size.width, size.height) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];                 
}
```

If I try to present the Popover from an UIButton it goes well...

Thanks!

Comment: In which method is this code defined?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
CGRect popoverRect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - self.popoverController.popoverContentSize.width,
                                CGRectGetMidY(cellRect),
                                1.0, 1.0);
```

The `x` location I use places the popover on the right-hand side of the screen. This may not be what you want. To find the actual touch point, you can use gesture recognizers.

In return, please try to answer my related question: [Popover's arrow to track an object in a scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442953/popovers-arrow-to-track-an-object-in-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating David's code I arrived at this:
(my pop is called "storytPop")- my popover is from the toolbar and I wanted the next tableview to show to the right.

```
CGRect cellRect = [self.tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
[self.storytPop presentPopoverFromRect:cellRect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```