# Popover's arrow to track an object in a scrollview

Tags: uitableview, ipad, uiscrollview, uipopovercontroller

I show a popover whenever a cell in my tableview is touched, with the arrow pointing to the cell, and always pointing left or right, not up or down.

The table view is set as the popover's `passthroughView`, so that the user can select a different cell while the popover is still open, resulting in a new popover for the selected cell.

However, this means that the user can also scroll the table while the popover is open. When this happens, how can I make the popover's arrow continue to point at the selected cell?

Unfortunately, UITableView *is*, not is contained in, a UIScrollView, so I can't simply present the popover in the tableview's coordinate system. Also, table cells do not seem to have a defined frame to present the popover from. I don't see any way in the API to move the popover's arrow manually.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out, you can use `presentPopoverFromRect:InView:` even when the popover has already been presented; this will cause the popover controller to recompute its arrow position.

Comment: This is documented in Technical Q&A QA1694: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1694.html

Comment: Just tested this on iOS 8 and it does not work (anymore). Calling the presentPopoverFromRect:InView:... does not update the UIPopoverController's arrow position once it has been added to the screen.