# Adjust UIPopoverController position after resize

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIPopoverController` containing a `UITableView`.  The popover is resized in its view controller's `-viewDidAppear` function to fit the contents of the table.  While the popover resizes properly, its arrow is usually no longer pointing at the original `CGRect`.  Is there a way to force the popover to reposition itself after a resize so that its arrow is pointing at its intended target?

**EDIT:** I can't set the size of the popover in `-viewDidLoad` since the table view does not load its data until `-viewDidAppear` is called, and as a result I do not know what size the popover should be until then.  In addition, I resize the popover when one of the table view cells is clicked to display another view and this also results in the arrow no longer pointing at its intended target.

Comment: You can set the size of the popover before the table is loaded. The two things are totally separate. What you are doing is setting the size of the encapsulating frame; if the `UITableView`'s actual content size is longer, you will get the scrollbars, just like what happens when you load a table view on an iPhone and the content is taller than 480 pixels.

Comment: @Shaggy Frog: I want to avoid scroll bars when possible.

Comment: Again, you misunderstand. Universally, if the content in a `UITableView` is taller than its frame, it will show scrollbars. That is a completely separate topic from what you are asking, which is adjusting the frame of a popover view, which I have explained how to do.

Comment: My question is actually a combination of the two topics: I am asking how to adjust the frame of a popover such that the UITableView it is containing will not show scrollbars (if possible), without allowing the popover's arrow to reposition itself.

Comment: There's no real easy way to do that. The implementation of the popover controller needs to know how big to make the encapsulating frame, so it knows where it's going to be positioned on the screen, so it knows where to position the arrow. The only way I can imagine around that would be to create an instance of the table view controller and have it show its view off-screen, then query the `UITableView` for its content size, and then dispose of this hidden view controller. It's dodgy. Maybe iOS 4.2 will have more control over popover controllers, but for now, you're flying too close to the sun.

Comment: I think you're right: it doesn't look like there is any easy way to do it.  One "solution" is to position the popover such that the arrow is pointing in the direction in which it shrinks/expands.

Answer (score 6):

I think this may be the wrong way to go about it, since you're having to re-do the built-in behaviour that positions the arrow to begin with.

I don't resize popover content in `viewDidAppear`. I set the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property in the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 155); // sized for a 3-row UITableView
}
```

(Quick warning: if you're developing a universal app, this code will cause a run-time crash on devices running 3.1.x and below.)

You can also set the content size for the popover controller before you present it, which should take care of your problem. Check out the [`popoverContentSize`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/popoverContentSize) property.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't work in my situation; see my updated question.

Comment: @ shaggy frog popovercontentsize is good idea `self.popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 300);` will do da job. thanks man

Comment: Note `contentSizeForViewInPopover` is deprecated as of 7.0

Answer (score 3):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442953/popovers-arrow-to-track-an-object-in-a-scrollview/3550455#3550455), you can call `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:` on the popover again and it will reposition the arrow. I haven't tested this myself.

Comment: This is documented in Technical Q&A QA1694: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2010/qa1694.html