# How to make UIPopoverController keep same position after rotating?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller, autorotate, uipopover

I can't keep popover the same position on the screen after rotation. Is there any good way to do that, because just setting some frame to popover works terrible after rotating.`popover.frame = CGRectMake(someFrame);` After rotation popover looks fine only if it is in the center of the screen.

Comment: Just check this link also..


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670981/adjust-uipopovercontroller-position-after-resize

Comment: Thanks for : presentPopoverFromRect:inView can be used when popover is visible

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Apple has a Q&A on exactly this issue. You can find the details here:

[Technical Q&A QA1694 Handling Popover Controllers During Orientation Changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1694/_index.html)

Basically, the technique explains that in your view controller's `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method, you will present the pop over again as follows:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:targetRect.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

For more information, have a read of the article above, and also the [UIPopoverController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If the user rotates the device while a popover is visible, the popover
>   controller hides the popover and then shows it again at the end of the
>   rotation. The popover controller attempts to position the popover
>   appropriately for you but you may have to present it again or hide it
>   altogether in some cases. For example, when displayed from a bar
>   button item, the popover controller automatically adjusts the position
>   (and potentially the size) of the popover to account for changes to
>   the position of the bar button item. However, if you remove the bar
>   button item during the rotation, or if you presented the popover from
>   a target rectangle in a view, the popover controller does not attempt
>   to reposition the popover. In those cases, you must manually hide the
>   popover or present it again from an appropriate new position. You can
>   do this in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method of the view
>   controller that you used to present the popover.

Comment: UIPopoverController is deprecated. You'll want to use UIPopoverPresentationController https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller

Answer (score 17):

As of iOS 8.0.2 willRotateToInterfaceOrientation **will not have any effect**. As mhrrt mentioned, you need to use the delegate method:

`- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view`

So for example if you want your popover to appear directly below a button that was pressed, you would use the following code:

```
- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view
{
   CGRect rectInView = [self.theButton convertRect:self.theButton.frame toView:self.view];
   *rect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(rectInView), CGRectGetMaxY(rectInView), 1, 1);
   *view = self.view;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In iOS 7 you can use `- (void)popoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect inView:(inout UIView *__autoreleasing *)view` to reposition your UIPopoverController's view on interface orientation change.

See the `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPopoverControllerDelegate/popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:).

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` method of the view controller that you used to present the popover.

Use `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` method for setting the size of the popover.

Comment: Does this method change the popover origin? I do not need to change the size of popover content, just to keep the origin.

Answer (score 4):

`UIPopoverController` was deprecated in ios9 in favor of [UIPopoverPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontroller) introduced in ios8. (I went through this transition also when going from `UIActionSheet` to `UIAlertController`.) You have two choices (example in obj-C):

A. Implement the `UIViewController` method below (UIKit calls this method before changing the size of a presented view controller’s view).

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size
           withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
        [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
        [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:nil
                                     completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> _Nonnull context) {
                                         // Fix up popover placement if necessary, *after* the transition.
                                         // Be careful here if a subclass also overrides this method.
                                         if (self.presentedViewController) {
                                             UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController =
                                                     [self.presentedViewController popoverPresentationController];
                                             UIView *selectedView = /** YOUR VIEW */;
                                             presentationController.sourceView = selectedView.superview;
                                             presentationController.sourceRect = selectedView.frame;
                                         }
                                     }];
    }
```

B. Alternatively, when configuring your `UIPopoverPresentationController` to present, also set its delegate. e.g. your presenting vc can implement `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` and assign itself as the delegate. Then implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)popoverPresentationController:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController
          willRepositionPopoverToRect:(inout CGRect *)rect
                               inView:(inout UIView * _Nonnull *)view {
    UIView *selectedView = /** YOUR VIEW */;
    // Update where the arrow pops out of in the view you selected.
    *view = selectedView;
    *rect = selectedView.bounds;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Option B worked flawlessly for me after many tries.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift:

```
func popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>)
{
    rect.pointee = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1) // Set new rect here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried just to set new rect (rect.initialize(...)) and it works.

```
func popoverPresentationController(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverToRect rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, inView view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView?>) {

        if popoverPresentationController.presentedViewController.view.tag == Globals.PopoverTempTag
        {
            rect.initialize(getForPopupSourceRect())
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problem which I resolve by this

```
[myPop presentPopoverFromRect:myfield.frame inView:myscrollview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Where `myfield` is frame from which you want to show your popover and `myscrollview` is container view in which you add your popover as subview(in my case its my scrollview, instead of putting `inView:self.view` I use `inView:myscrollview`).

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize PopOver Controller

   ```
   var popoverContent: PopoverContentViewController?
   ```
2. Write Defination for PopOver Controller

   ```
   popoverContent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopoverContentViewController") as? PopoverContentViewController
   popoverContent?.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
   let popover = popoverContent?.popoverPresentationController!
   popover?.delegate = self
   popoverContent?.preQuestionInfoPopUpViewDelegateObject = self
   popover?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection()
   popover?.sourceView = self.view
   popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 330, height: 330)
   ```
3. Present PopOver Controller

   self.present(popoverContent, animated: true, completion:nil)
4. Write below method and assign new size to popover:

   override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
           let popover = popoverContent?.popoverPresentationController!
           popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2, width: 0, height: 0)
   }

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Instead of performing `-presentPopoverFromRect` each time by keeping track of the source rectangle / view from which it is presented, I subclassed `UIPopoverController`. After doing it, all you have to do is set either the UIBarButtonItem / UIView from where the popover has to be displayed. You can even opt for displaying the popover from custom frame which can be passed in as a NSString value.

**CSPopoverController.h**:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// The original popover controller would not re-orientate itself when the orientation change occurs. To tackle that issue, this subclass is created
@interface CSPopoverController : UIPopoverController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *popoverDisplaySourceFrame;  // Mutually Exclusive. If you want to set custom rect as source, make sure that popOverDisplaySource is nil
@property (nonatomic, strong) id popoverDisplaySource;              // Mutually exclusive. If UIBarButtonItem is set to it, popoverDisplaySourceFrame is neglected.
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *popoverDisplayView;

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = shouldAutomaticallyReorientate) BOOL automaticallyReorientate;

-(void)reorientatePopover;

@end
```

**CSPopoverController.m**:

```
#import "CSPopoverController.h"

@implementation CSPopoverController
@synthesize popoverDisplaySourceFrame = popoverDisplaySourceFrame_;
-(NSString*)popoverDisplaySourceFrame
{
    if (nil==popoverDisplaySourceFrame_)
    {
        if (nil!=self.popoverDisplaySource)
        {
            if ([self.popoverDisplaySource isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
            {
                UIView *viewSource = (UIView*)self.popoverDisplaySource;
                [self setPopoverDisplaySourceFrame:NSStringFromCGRect(viewSource.frame)];
            }
        }
    }
    return popoverDisplaySourceFrame_;
}
-(void)setPopoverDisplaySourceFrame:(NSString *)inPopoverDisplaySourceFrame
{
    if (inPopoverDisplaySourceFrame!=popoverDisplaySourceFrame_)
    {
        popoverDisplaySourceFrame_ = inPopoverDisplaySourceFrame;
        [self reorientatePopover];
    }
}
@synthesize popoverDisplaySource = popoverDisplaySource_;
-(void)setPopoverDisplaySource:(id)inPopoverDisplaySource
{
    if (inPopoverDisplaySource!=popoverDisplaySource_)
    {
        [self unlistenForFrameChangeInView:popoverDisplaySource_];
        popoverDisplaySource_ = inPopoverDisplaySource;
        [self reorientatePopover];

        if ([popoverDisplaySource_ isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
        {
            UIView *viewSource = (UIView*)popoverDisplaySource_;
            [self setPopoverDisplaySourceFrame:NSStringFromCGRect(viewSource.frame)];
        }
        if (self.shouldAutomaticallyReorientate)
        {
            [self listenForFrameChangeInView:popoverDisplaySource_];
        }
    }
}
@synthesize popoverDisplayView = popoverDisplayView_;
-(void)setPopoverDisplayView:(UIView *)inPopoverDisplayView
{
    if (inPopoverDisplayView!=popoverDisplayView_)
    {
        popoverDisplayView_ = inPopoverDisplayView;
        [self reorientatePopover];
    }
}
@synthesize automaticallyReorientate = automaticallyReorientate_;
-(void)setAutomaticallyReorientate:(BOOL)inAutomaticallyReorientate
{
    if (inAutomaticallyReorientate!=automaticallyReorientate_)
    {
        automaticallyReorientate_ = inAutomaticallyReorientate;
        if (automaticallyReorientate_)
        {
            [self listenForAutorotation];
            [self listenForFrameChangeInView:self.popoverDisplaySource];
        }
        else
        {
            [self unlistenForAutorotation];
            [self unlistenForFrameChangeInView:self.popoverDisplaySource];
        }
    }
}

-(void)listenForAutorotation
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)unlistenForAutorotation
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}

-(void)listenForFrameChangeInView:(id)inView
{
    // Let's listen for changes in the view's frame and adjust the popover even if the frame is updated
    if ([inView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
    {
        UIView *viewToObserve = (UIView*)inView;
        [viewToObserve addObserver:self
                        forKeyPath:@"frame"
                           options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                           context:nil];
    }
}

-(void)unlistenForFrameChangeInView:(id)inView
{
    if ([inView isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
    {
        UIView *viewToObserve = (UIView*)inView;
        [viewToObserve removeObserver:self
                           forKeyPath:@"frame"];
    }
}

// TODO: Dealloc is not called, check why? !!!
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self unlistenForFrameChangeInView:self.popoverDisplaySource];
    [self unlistenForAutorotation];
    DEBUGLog(@"dealloc called for CSPopoverController %@", self);
}

#pragma mark - Designated initializers
-(id)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    self = [super initWithContentViewController:viewController];
    if (self)
    {
        [self popoverCommonInitializations];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)popoverCommonInitializations
{
    [self setAutomaticallyReorientate:YES];
}

#pragma mark - Frame
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object==self.popoverDisplaySource)
    {
        [self setPopoverDisplaySourceFrame:nil];
        [self reorientatePopover];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Orientation
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)inNotification
{
    [self reorientatePopover];
}

-(void)reorientatePopover
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                             selector:@selector(performReorientatePopover)
                                               object:nil];
//    if ([self isPopoverVisible])
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(performReorientatePopover)
                   withObject:nil
                   afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}

-(void)performReorientatePopover
{
    if (self.popoverDisplaySourceFrame && self.popoverDisplayView)
    {
        [self presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectFromString(self.popoverDisplaySourceFrame)
                              inView:self.popoverDisplayView
            permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                            animated:YES];
    }
    else if (self.popoverDisplaySource && [self.popoverDisplaySource isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]])
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem*)self.popoverDisplaySource;
        [self presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButton
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

**Usage:**

If it is a UIBarButtonItem from where you are presenting it:

```
CSPopoverController *popOverCont = [[CSPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navCont];
self.popOver = popOverCont;
[popOverCont setPopoverDisplaySource:self.settingsButtonItem];
```

If it is a UIView from where you are presenting the popover:

```
CSPopoverController *popOver = [[CSPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigation];
self.iPadPopoverController = popOver;
[newDateVC setIPadPopoverController:self.iPadPopoverController];
[popOver setPopoverDisplaySource:inButton];
[popOver setPopoverDisplayView:inView];
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS > 8 John Strickers answer helped but didn't do what I wanted it to do.

Here's the solution that worked for me. (If you want to download a full sample project it's here: https://github.com/appteur/uipopoverExample)

I created a property to hold any popover I wanted to present and also added a property to track the sourceRect and another for the view of the button I wanted the popover arrow to point at.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *activePopoverBtn;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PopoverViewController *popoverVC;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect sourceRect;
```

The button that triggered my popover is in a UIToolbar. When tapped it runs the following method that creates and launches the popover.

```
-(void) buttonAction:(id)sender event:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"ButtonAction");

    // when the button is tapped we want to display a popover, so setup all the variables needed and present it here

    // get a reference to which button's view was tapped (this is to get 
    // the frame to update the arrow to later on rotation)
    // since UIBarButtonItems don't have a 'frame' property I found this way is easy
    UIView *buttonView          = [[event.allTouches anyObject] view];

    // set our tracker properties for when the orientation changes (handled in the viewWillTransitionToSize method above)
    self.activePopoverBtn       = buttonView;
    self.sourceRect             = buttonView.frame;

    // get our size, make it adapt based on our view bounds
    CGSize viewSize             = self.view.bounds.size;
    CGSize contentSize          = CGSizeMake(viewSize.width, viewSize.height - 100.0);

    // set our popover view controller property
    self.popoverVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PopoverVC"];

    // configure using a convenience method (if you have multiple popovers this makes it faster with less code)
    [self setupPopover:self.popoverVC
        withSourceView:buttonView.superview // this will be the toolbar
            sourceRect:self.sourceRect
           contentSize:contentSize];

    [self presentViewController:self.popoverVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The 'setupPopover:withSourceView:sourceRect:contentSize method is simply a convenience method to set the popoverPresentationController properties if you plan to display multiple popovers and want them configured the same. It's implementation is below.

```
// convenience method in case you want to display multiple popovers
-(void) setupPopover:(UIViewController*)popover withSourceView:(UIView*)sourceView sourceRect:(CGRect)sourceRect contentSize:(CGSize)contentSize
{
    NSLog(@"\npopoverPresentationController: %@\n", popover.popoverPresentationController);

    popover.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popover.popoverPresentationController.delegate = self;
    popover.popoverPresentationController.sourceView                = sourceView;
    popover.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect                = sourceRect;
    popover.preferredContentSize                                    = contentSize;
    popover.popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections  = UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown;
    popover.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor           = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

For iOS 8 and up the viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator get's called on the view controller when the device rotates.

I implemented this method in my presenting view controller class as shown below.

```
// called when rotating a device
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillTransitionToSize [%@]", NSStringFromCGSize(size));

    // resizes popover to new size and arrow location on orientation change
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context)
    {
        if (self.popoverVC)
        {
            // get the new frame of our button (this is our new source rect)
            CGRect viewframe = self.activePopoverBtn ? self.activePopoverBtn.frame : CGRectZero;

            // update our popover view controller's sourceRect so the arrow will be pointed in the right place
            self.popoverVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = viewframe;

            // update the preferred content size if we want to adapt the size of the popover to fit the new bounds
            self.popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width -20, self.view.bounds.size.height - 100);
        }

    } completion:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {
        // anything you want to do when the transition completes
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
    class MyClass: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


        ...

        var popover:UIPopoverPresentationController?

        ...

        // Where you want to set the popover...
        popover = YourViewController?.popoverPresentationController
        popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        popover?.delegate = self

        ...

        // override didRotate...
        override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
          popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
        }

}
```

Comment: `didRotate` is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621492-didrotate). You should be using one of the two approaches I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41561021/954643, e.g. `popoverPresentationController(_:willRepositionPopoverTo:in:)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontrollerdelegate/1622326-popoverpresentationcontroller?preferredLanguage=swift)) This is in part because you can change the layout of a screen by more than rotations now, such as through the split-screen multitasking features in ios9+

Answer (score 0):

I have popoverPresentationController that I present on a view that has a "fake" nav bar. So I can't attach the popoverPresentationController to a barButtonItem. My popup appears in the right place but does not when the screen rotates.

So for some reason `popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>)` does not get called for me.

To work around this (iOS 12, Swift 4.2) I added constraints to the popup in the completion closure when calling present. Now my popup stays where I would expect it too.

```
                present(viewController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
            DDLogDebug(String(describing: viewController.view.frame))
            if let containerView = viewController.popoverPresentationController?.containerView,
            let presentedView = viewController.popoverPresentationController?.presentedView,
            let imageView = self?.headerView.settingsButton {
                withExtendedLifetime(self) {
                    let deltaY:CGFloat = presentedView.frame.origin.y - imageView.frame.maxY
                    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: presentedView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: imageView.imageView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: deltaY)
                    topConstraint?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
                    topConstraint?.isActive = true
                    let heightContraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: presentedView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.75, constant: -deltaY)
                    heightContraint?.isActive = true
                    let leftConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: presentedView, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: presentedView.frame.origin.x)
                    leftConstraint.isActive = true
                    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.init(item: presentedView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: presentedView.frame.width)
                    widthConstraint.isActive = true
                    presentedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                }
            }
        }
```